# Where does Ubuntu store the cache of MAC addresses for interface numbering?

Tags: networking, virtualization

Example: I run Ubu in a VM.  I remove and add several network cards.  Suddenly, I'm at eth4.  I want to migrate this VM to openstack.  How can I find/purge the MAC address cache for interfaces, so a vm behaves as I would expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you edit the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. I'd remove all the lines for previous, no longer installed network cards; change the current interface, for example `eth4`, to `eth0` and reboot.

Comment: If you remove the file it will re-number your NICs, assuming you only have one it will be eth0

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins - That is an excellent point.  If you added some detail about how removal is required, not just suggested, to conform to the openstack deployment requirements for not having a static MAC address requirement, it would be a better answer than the current accepted answer for the use case of openstack (although this one does answer the question in general).